# Creating a sequence of IP addresses if given a starting address

Tags: ruby

I need to write code to ping a sequence of 20 IP addresses if given a starting IP address (e.g 192.168.0.1). Each successive IP address should be one digit larger than the previous.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking how to generate 19 valid IP addresses that differ by only one digit from a given one, or how to ping?

Comment: i want to generate the next 19 ip addresses.

Answer (score 5):

That's what [`IPAddr#succ`](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/ipaddr/IPAddr%3asucc) is for:

```
require 'ipaddr'

ipaddr = IPAddr.new('192.168.0.1')

20.times do
  ping ipaddr
  ipaddr = ipaddr.succ
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ip = "192.168.0.1"
ips = []

(0..20).each do |n|

  temp = ip.split('.').map(&:to_i)

  temp[3] = temp[3] + n

  ips << temp.join('.')

end

puts ips
```

Comment: You should use 1..19 instead I think. And you should do the split outside the each block since you just need to do it once

Comment: You may need to consider boundary cases - what happens when the final digit in the IP address reaches 255?